# jQuery - how to get string value of selector without the prefix

Tags: jquery, string, jquery-selectors

How do I get the string 'unenable-item' assuming that it is used as part of the string in a selector such as:

```
$('.unenable-item').click(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

thx

Comment: If you already have the string as the selector, why would you need to find it programmatically?

Comment: pass it as arg to be called against api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.unenable-item').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Or more generic way

```
$('.unenable-item').click(function(){
  alert($('.unenable-item').selector);
});
```

In this case you will get `.unenable-item` and you must work with that string and get substring that you want.

**EDIT:**

`.selector` property can't work with `$(this)` and will return always empty string, because it making new object every time. So I find solution to work with that. The solution is to make new function for binding events and use that function instead of simple jquery functions.

*Usage*

```
jQuery.fn.addEvent = function(type, handler) {
    this.bind(type, {'selector': this.selector}, handler);
};
```

And after this you can simply get your selector

```
$('.unenable-item').addEvent('click', function(event) {
        alert(event.data.selector);
});
```

Note, that I used `addEvent` method for binding click, instead of immediately binding by Jquery's `click` function.

You can see example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DFh7z/21/

Comment: But what if it has 2 classes?

Comment: I've edited my answer and included generic way to get selector.

Comment: Edited for you as you were missing a closing bracket.

Comment: never seen that syntax - is it recent jQuery version?

Comment: @timpone, I just write wrong name of property. It's selector and not getselector :)